# Fix laminate kitchen counter finish

Tags: finishing, wood-repair

Recently, I bought a kitchen with a veneered wood top, with black marble-effect finish.

The guys that assembled the kitchen used some silicone to join the two pieces of the top, leaving a horrible layer of silicone near the joint. This in backlight looks shiny and contrasts with the rest of the top.

So I've tried to remove it and successfully got 90 % of it off, but with the sanding action of the cloth, the top still looks shiny. Are there any products that I can use to make it look like the rest of top (like oils, lacquer, ...)?

[image: The area is near the sink]

Comment: Have any good pictures of what you are talking about to help us out a little bit?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking, but I'm voting to close as this is minimally to do with woodworking. It's not perfectly clear what it is you need here but if you are looking for a product that will make the remaining silicone look like the surrounding surface there's nothing really that will work — even if you match the gloss *exactly* it will still be very visible. So instead I suggest you work hard to remove that last 10%. Using plastic scrapers is probably your safest bet here, but a hardwood block with a sharp corner might work as well and should also not risk damaging the laminate surface.

Comment: Depending on where you are in the world, you might be able to buy a product that dissolves cured silicone. Apply that to the edges, and you might be able to minimize the gloss.

Comment: This weekend I'll update with the photo

Comment: @Graphus The problem is not really the remaining silicone, but "scraped" area that was covered with silicone, still look shiny (maybe the silicone is penetrated, or it's because I've scraped it with a cloth now is more reflective than the surrounding area). BTW Thanks for the edit

Comment: If the gloss level in those areas is the only issue you might (*might*) be able to fix it with a 'magic eraser' type cleaner (these are made from foamed malamine). I don't know if you have those in the house already or if they're easily available where you are but this material is a very good very mild abrasive that could be just enough to do what you need here. Beyond this even fine steel wool is possibly too aggressive and would risk damaging the surrounding surface, and I think any sanding with abrasive papers is out unless you were a very experienced user.